# Opening application then closing it (Pyglet & Threading)

Tags: python

What I am trying to do is open a window, wait 8 seconds then close it, every time is use the code, the error message is:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'flip'

Here is code

```
import pyglet
from threading import Timer

ag_file = "loading2.gif"
animation = pyglet.resource.animation(ag_file)
sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(animation)
win = pyglet.window.Window(width=sprite.width, height=sprite.height)
def close():
  win.close()
  return close
t = Timer(8.0, close)

@win.event
def on_draw():
  win.clear()
  sprite.draw()
t.start()
pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: second thread may close window when main thread is executing function which use `flip` so it can't find window because second thread destroyed window.

Comment: pyglet has own function to safly execut function with delay - http://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/programming_guide/time.html

Answer (score 1):

In the same time when you close window in second thread then main thread may be using window to draw image and it can't find it because second thread closed window.

Pyglet has own methods to safely execute function with delay (or periodically) without `thread`

http://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/programming_guide/time.html

```
import pyglet

ag_file = "loading2.gif"

animation = pyglet.resource.animation(ag_file)
sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(animation)

win = pyglet.window.Window(width=sprite.width, height=sprite.height)

@win.event
def on_draw():
    win.clear()
    sprite.draw()

def close(event):
    win.close()

pyglet.clock.schedule_once(close, 8.0)

pyglet.app.run()
```